# Restoring a Ubuntu Linux LVM drive

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Scenario: I have a hard disk with a bootable `sda1` partition and an Linux LVM.  I seem to have corrupted the MBR? or Grub?  not sure.  I know it no longer boots and even with boot-repair and a Ubuntu live usb I was able to restore it.  Following a "fix" with boot-repair I got `missing operating system` error

Can't i just reinstall grub or a new `menu.lst`?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007b68f

Device Boot        Start    End         Blocks     Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      2048     499711      248832     83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   625141759   312320001  5   Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   625141759   312320000  8e  Linux LVM
```